# NFS: can't stat exported dir: invalid argument

Tags: linux, nfs

I recently had the NFS mount point on my server stop working. On the client side, I get the following:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.10.6:/media/storage/archive
```

On the server side, the logs show:

```
Jun 22 16:34:57 serverf rpc.mountd[31675]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.10.153:696 for /media/storage/archive (/media/storage/archive)
Jun 22 16:34:57 serverf rpc.mountd[31675]: can't stat exported dir /media/storage/archive: Invalid argument
```

I've tried from multiple clients (including localhost) and with different exports on different filesystems but to no avail. Always the same error, but no info on what the invalid argument is, and I'm unsure of why this just started happening.

Additional info:

```
[root@serverf ~]# ls -lai /media/storage
total 28
 17 drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 17  2014 .
 16 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 15  2014 ..
256 drwxrwxr-x  1 root root  210 Feb  6 18:24 archive
 20 drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 Jun 17 16:04 gdrive
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message seems to be saying that `/media/storage/archive`
***is*** the invalid argument. 
If you do

```
ls -lai /media/storage
```

(on the server),
you’ll probably see that the `archive` directory is missing or damaged.

If not, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1451826/edit) your question to include the output of the above command.

Comment: The directory I'm exporting seems to be good. I did also try different directories for export and none are working. The output of of the ls command is added to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exact same issue after an Archlinux upgrade the NFS share was no longer mountable with the same rcp.mountd error.
My solution was to downgrade `nfs-utils`, `rpcbind`, and `nfsidmap` using the following commands:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/nfs-utils-2.3.4-1-arm.pkg.tar.xz
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/nfsidmap-2.3.4-1-arm.pkg.tar.xz
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/rpcbind-1.2.5-1-arm.pkg.tar.xz
```

once this was done I excluded the packages from future upgrades by adding this line

```
IgnorePkg   = nfs-utils rbcbind nfsidmap
```

to `/etc/pacman.conf`.

After a reboot the NFS exports were mountable again and I hope this issue will be fixed in some future releases of `rpcbind`.

Hope this helps ...

cheers, MuS